# Regex - Company name

Tags: regex

I have a plain text and need to extract company names. It's a huge document including company names, financial reports and lots of text.Here are **examples** of company names:

- Big laundry, a.s.
- AVERA, s.r.o.
- Airoflot Airlines, a.s.

Is it even possible to make regex like this? I'm complete beginner to regex and have no idea how to create this one. Thanks for any help.

Example of text:

`There are many competitors of AVERA, s.r.o. the main one is Airflot Airlines, a.s. and Big laundry, s.r.o. These organisations hold main share of market.
Another companies:

a. Big Company, a.s.

b. Smaller company, s.r.o.

c. Huge company, a.s.`

Comment: How are the values separated? CSV? New lines?

Comment: Do you have an example of the plain text format you can add?

Comment: Your company names seem to follow this pattern : `[\w ]+,(\w\.)+`.

Comment: they are placed freely in text. but each on its own line. there could be any character before each name.

Comment: How should the regexp figure out where the company name begins?

Comment: +1 @Barmar : that's the main problem here.

Comment: Regular expressions don't have AI. You need to describe precisely what the rules are for matching company names, then we can tell you if those rules can be translated into an RE. A few examples don't do it.

Comment: @user2285265: I have deleted my answer because question is not very clear. I suggest you to post a small snippet of your text document containing these company names and give examples of company names to be captured from that text file.

Answer (score 0):

As the question currently stands, no it is not possible to create a regex for company names.

It would be possible if you are able to create a PATTERN.

Means e.g. A company name always:

- starts with an uppercase letter
- has a comma
- after the comma there is always one of "a.s." or "s.r.o."

So, the difficulties that I see here are:

- How many words before the comma belong to the name?
- Is there always a comma with following abbreviation?

**Names are always difficult to match because a name can be nearly everything, especially company names.**

Answer (score 0):

The examples you give follow this pattern : `([A-Z][A-Za-z]+ ?)+, (\w\.)+`

The matching operation will be dependent of the tool you use.

For example in JavaScript :

```
var line = "some name is Airoflot Airlines, a.s. in this line";
var m = line.match(/([A-Z][A-Za-z]+ ?)+, (\w\.)+/);
if (m.length) console.log(m[0]);
```

This logs

```
"Airoflot Airlines, a.s."
```

But this isn't a very reliable solutions : many real company names wouldn't fit and, more importantly perhaps, this would match sentences that aren't company names. So this can only be used as an help in a solution which also incorporates some kind of validation (human or dictionary based).

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,_\.\077\0100\*\+\&\#\'\~\;\-\!\@\;]{2,}\s*)*
```

it matches all a-z, A-Z,0-9 and some special characters which Quickbook supports.
https://community.intuit.com/articles/1146006-acceptable-characters-in-the-company-name-in-quickbooks-online

Answer (score -1):

with your given examples, this regexp would match

```
Big laundry, a\.s\.|AVERA, s\.r\.o\.|Airoflot Airlines, a\.s\.
```

The trick is to use the alternation operator | on a set of strings

You may wish to consider missing punctuation and white space in the company names too

Comment: He said they're just examples, not the only company names he needs to match.

Comment: @Barmar if you are dealing with free text and you do not know the names of the companies in advance, then this problem is very difficult and the OP has not given enough detail to even start on it.  OTOH, if the names of the companies *are* known then making a list of them with the alternation operator makes *perfect* sense.  Although I've used the examples, this technique would work with any known company names

Comment: People voting down this answer should provide their own, better answer.  This provides a known pattern for this type of match